# Is it appropriate to say "try all this tasty food" when referring to lots of tasty food?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

"I wish I had the chance to try all this tasty food."
Is it appropriate to say "try all this tasty food" when referring to lots of tasty food mentioned in the previous context?
What about "try all the tasty food" , “try all these tasty food" or “try all these tasty foods" ?

Comment: _This_ or _the_ are both OK. _Food_ here is an uncountable noun, so _these food_ and _these foods_ are wrong. (_Foods_ in the plural means _types of food_, but we use it in a scientific or commercial sense, not of dishes on a table.)

Comment: Hello, Kate, thank you very much for your clear explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*this* is a proximal pronoun meaning it can be used even for something that wasn't mentioned/introduced as long as it's within your (and your addressee's) reach.

Both are fine.

> Try all this/the tasty food

As pointed out by @Kate Bunting, the plural form is not used in such contexts.

Comment: Hello, Andrew, thank you very much for you answer too.